# Child of data object not being evaluated until logged. Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am writing a component (`form`) that acts as a container for form fields that are passed from the parent component.

I pass the form fields to the child as a prop:

```
formFields: [
    { name: 'email', type: 'email' },
    {
        name: 'sub_group',
        type: 'group',
        contents: [
            { name: 'sub_field_01', type: 'text' },
            { name: 'sub_field_02', type: 'text' },
        ]
    }
]
```

That is all displayed fine and works well in my child component.

I used a computed property to build up data to post to a route to update the resource. I group the `sub_group` so that when I am posting, the controller understands that the `sub_group` is an array.

However, the `sub_group` array is always empty *until I console log it*, so it only evaluates when logged. The top level (`email` in this case) always shows up.

I have tried getting rid of the computed property and use a method to build up the object to post but I have the same issue. I really have no idea what is happening. How can 'force' the computed property to evaluate?

**EDIT Adding form example**

Code that renders the form:

```
<div v-for="field in formFields">
    <!-- Individual Field -->
    <div v-if="field.type !== 'group'">
        <label v-if="field.label">{{ field.label }}</label>
        <input :type="field.type" :name="field.name" v-model="field.value">   
    </div>
    <!-- Group -->
    <div v-else>
        <div v-for="child in field.group">
            <label v-if="child.label">{{ child.label }}</label>
            <input :type="child.type" :name="child.name" v-model="child.value">   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Computed property for post:

```
<div v-for="field in formFields">
    <!-- Individual Field -->
    <div v-if="field.type !== 'group'">
        <label v-if="field.label">{{ field.label }}</label>
        <input :type="field.type" :name="field.name" v-model="field.value">   
    </div>
    <!-- Group -->
    <div v-else>
        <div v-for="child in field.group">
            <label v-if="child.label">{{ child.label }}</label>
            <input :type="child.type" :name="child.name" v-model="child.value">   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I realise this needs refactoring but I can't actually get it working like this. I have tried adding `cache:false` and a getter to the computed property but that didn't work.

Comment: The computed is only watching for changes to `formFields` at the top level, and it caches it's value so on posting the original empty formfield is returned. Perhaps do the processing in an onsubmit, or a deep watcher may be useful. Would need to see more of the code.

Comment: Show form rendering code, please.